# How to align images at center of div on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/14jkh4qb/. I want to align `images(Facebook,Twitter)` (initially they will be hidden) at center of main `div (class box)` on mouse over and the opacity of my `div (class box)` to `0.1`

Can I manage it with CSS only or I have to write some `Js` code for that

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {
 padding: 5px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 20px auto;
}
header {
 height: 100px;
 padding: 0 15px;
}
#content {
 width: 290px;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}

#middle {
 width: 294px; /* Account for margins + border values */
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#sidebar {
 width: 270px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 float: left;
}
footer {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

/************************************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*************************************************************************************/
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
 
 #pagewrap {
  width: 94%;
 }
 #content {
  width: 41%;
  padding: 1% 4%;
 }
 #middle {
  width: 41%;
  padding: 1% 4%;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  float: right;
 }
 
 #sidebar {
  clear: both;
  padding: 1% 4%;
  width: auto;
  float: none;
 }

 header, footer {
  padding: 1% 4%;
 }
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 #content {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
 }
 
 #middle {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
 
 #sidebar {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
 }

}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 
 h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
 }
 #sidebar {
  display: none;
 }

}


#content {
 /*background: #f8f8f8;*/
}
#sidebar {
 /*background: #f0efef;*/
}
header, #content, #middle, #sidebar {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#pagewrap, header, #content, #middle, #sidebar, footer {
 /*border: solid 1px #ccc;*/
}

.inner1{
    float:left; 
    width:100%;
    /*background-color:#D9DFD8*/
    height:50px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    /*padding-left: .5cm;*/
    padding-top: .5cm;
    
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
   }
   .inner2{
    float:left; 
    clear: left;
    /*background-color:#CCCCCC;*/
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:.2cm;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
   }
   .output1{
   float:left; 
   width:33%;
   background-color:#D9DFD8;
   height:50px;
   text-align: justify;
   text-justify: inter-word;
   padding-left: .5cm;
   padding-top: .5cm;
   }
   .output2{
   float:left; 
   clear: left;
   background-color:#CCCCCC;
   width:33%;
   height:50px;
   padding-top:.2cm;
   }
   .left-span{
    padding-left: .2cm;
   }
   .right-span{
    padding-left:130px;
   }
   
   .button {
     font-family: tahoma;
     font-size: 8pt;
     line-height: 12px;
     margin-right: 5px;
     margin-top: 0;
     position: absolute;
     margin-left:-10px;
   }
   .community {
     
     margin-top: 15px;
     margin-left: 15px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:8;
   }
   #outputbox{
    display:none;
   }
   
 
   #main-wrap {
    /*background-color: #D9D9D9;*/
   }
   
   #sidebar-left {
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
   }
   
   #content-wrap {
   /*background-color: #c5c5c5;*/
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   -webkit-align-content: center;
   align-content: center;
   }
   
   /* sizes */
   #main-wrap > div {
    min-height: 100px;    
   }

   #main-wrap > div { min-height: 100px; }
   

   /* layout */
   #main-wrap {
    /* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   
   #sidebar-left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
   }
   
   #content-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
   } 
   #sidebar-right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    /*background-color: #c5c5c5;*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;
    position:relative;
   } 
   .bottom-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5;
   }
   .container-item {   display: block;   margin: 5px 0;}
      .box:hover{
        opacity:0.2
      }
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">

 <header>
  <h1>2 Column Responsive Layout</h1>
 </header>
  
 <section id="content">
   <div class="box">
   
    <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">Cat1_1</span></div>
    <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">10 Customers</span><span class="right-span">2016</span></div>
    <div>                 
     <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"    />
          <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
    </div>
   
   </div>
   <div style="padding:70px;"></div>
   
   <div class="box" >
    <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">Cat1_2</span></div>
    <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">10 Customers</span><span class="right-span">2016</span></div>
    <div>                 
     <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"   />
          <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
    </div>
   </div>
  
   <div style="padding:70px;"></div>
   
   <div class="box">
    <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">Cat1_3</span></div>
    <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">10 Customers</span><span class="right-span">2016</span></div>
    <div>                 
     <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"   />
          <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
    </div>
   </div>
  
 </section>
 
 <section id="middle">
  
   <div class="box" >
    <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double Green;"><span class="left-span">Cat2_1</span></div>
    <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double Green;"><span class="left-span">10 Customers</span><span class="right-span">2016</span></div>
    <div>                 
     <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"    />
          <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div style="padding:70px;"></div>
  
  
   <div class="box" >
    <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double Green;"><span class="left-span">Cat2_2</span></div>
    <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double Green;"><span class="left-span">10 Customers</span><span class="right-span">2016</span></div>
    <div>                 
     <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"    />
          <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
    </div>
   </div>
  
   <div style="padding:70px;"></div>
  
   <div class="box">
    <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double Green;"><span class="left-span">Cat2_3</span></div>
    <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double Green;"><span class="left-span">10 Customers</span><span class="right-span">2016</span></div>
    <div>                 
     <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"    />
          <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
    </div>
   </div>
  
 </section>

 
 
 <footer>
  <h4>Footer</h4>
  <p>Footer text</p>
 </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: You can manage it with just CSS ... please include the relevant code here.

Comment: I have added the `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/14jkh4qb/

Comment: You are an experienced user of SO ... you must know your question needs to be strong without any outter link. If the link goes down then the question will become useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here **: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/83gfep3n/1/)**

you can do this with `position:absolute`

added this code :

```
.box div:last-child {
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  transition:0.3s;
  opacity:0;
}
.box {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.box:hover div:last-child{
  opacity:1;
}

.box:hover div:not(:last-child) {
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

removed the `box:hover{opacity:0.2}` from your code because that made everything ( including the images ) to have the opacity 0.2 on hover

there are more ways to do this. this is just one of the solutions. let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `.box` divs with this one:

```
<div class="box" >
  <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;">
     <span class="left-span">Cat1_2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;">
     <span class="left-span">10 Customers</span>
     <span class="right-span">2016</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center hidden">
      <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"   />
      <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And add this CSS stuff with your own :

```
.box{
  position:relative;
}
.box:hover .center{
  display:block;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.center{  
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:20%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a class name for the div(e.g. images) within which the images are there.

```
<div class="box">

    <div class="inner1" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">Cat1_1</span></div>
    <div class="inner2" style="border-left: thick double #ff0000;"><span class="left-span">10 Customers</span><span class="right-span">2016</span></div>
    <div class="images">                                 
      <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/t_small-a.png"    />
      <img src="http://www.islandcarcentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon-small-facebook.png" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Add the following CSS:

```
  .box{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

  .box .images{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 40%;
  }


  .box:hover .images{
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .box:hover .inner1, .box:hover .inner2{
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only need to add the CSS bellow and add a class to the image wraper.

https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanck/14jkh4qb/1/

```
.inner-img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 105px;
    margin-left: 135px;
}
.box:hover .inner-img {
    display: block!important;
    opacity:1;
}
.box:hover div:not(.inner-img) {
  opacity:0.2;
}
```